# workflow git spy remote

Tags: git, git-remote

Suppose I have a bare repository A, it has branch master. I create local repository and add A as a remote. I want the local repository never push to remote, but it can commit local and pull from remote.

```
bare repository:      o-----o------------o
                      |     |            |
                    pull   pull         pull
                      |     |            |
local repository:     o-----o-------x----o

o: commit of bare repository (some devs make).
x: commit of mine in local and not pushed.
```

With git, can I do that?

Comment: You can specify an empty *push* url using the [`git remote`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote) command.  Why would you want something like this though?

Comment: Are you using something like gitolite to manage the remote repository? http://gitolite.com/gitolite/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that. It is even the basic functionning of git: you change your local copy and when you want to `push`, you first have to `pull` from the remote and solve any conflict (that git can see, i.e. changes to the same lines).

Simply be aware that if you never `push` your changes to the remote, your version will differ more and more and the incompatibilities will grow (for example your create a function, then a function with the same name and scope is created on the remote), and `git` will not detect it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do server-side ACLs using the git hook mechanism as described here:

http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-An-Example-Git-Enforced-Policy

You add a script into the `git hooks` directory of the bare repo on the remote

`.git/hooks/update`

You can test the script out in your local repo before putting it up on the remote bare repo.